# MAUI Sharpnado CollectionView drag and drop doesn't work

Tags: c#, drag-and-drop, maui, collectionview, tabbedpage

I use Sharpnado CollectionView, I move from mainpage to tabbedpage, and from it I use contentpage, so in this case, only drag function works and drop does not. if I use just contentpage separately from tabbedpage everything works.

There's only one button on the mainpage, and it's clickable (maybe there's a problem here, but I can't find a good way to go to the tabbed page).

```
private async void ToBubleSort_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    App.Current.MainPage = new TabbedPageBubleSort();
}
```

in tabbedpage

```
<TabbedPage
    x:Class="AlgorithmsApp.ThemePages.BubleSort.TabbedPageBubleSort"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:AlgorithmsApp.ThemePages.BubleSort">

    <local:TheoryPageBubleSort Title="Theory" /> 

    <local:ExercisePageBubleSort Title="Exercise" />
</TabbedPage>
```

no need to show my exercisepage because its work in way without tabbedpage  but i will show it just in case

```
<StackLayout Background="White" Orientation="Vertical">



    <sho:CollectionView
        x:Name="myCollection"
        CollectionLayout="Vertical"
        CollectionPadding="0,30,0,30"
        EnableDragAndDrop="True"
        ItemHeight="120">


        <sho:CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <sho:DraggableViewCell x:Name="DraggableViewCell">
                    <StackLayout Margin="5" Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Label
                            Padding="20"
                            FontSize="22"
                            Text="{Binding Text}"
                            TextColor="Green" />
                    </StackLayout>
                </sho:DraggableViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </sho:CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    </sho:CollectionView>


    <Button
        x:Name="check"
        Padding="10"
        BackgroundColor="AliceBlue"
        Clicked="check_Clicked"
        CornerRadius="25"
        HeightRequest="100"
        Text="Проверить"
        VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand"
        WidthRequest="250" />

    <Frame BorderColor="White" HeightRequest="150" />

</StackLayout>
```

and exercisepage.cs

```
 List<ExerciseItem> items = new List<ExerciseItem>
     {
         new ExerciseItem { Text = "Element 2", OrderId = 1},
         new ExerciseItem { Text = "Element 1", OrderId = 0},
         new ExerciseItem { Text = "Element 3", OrderId = 2 }
     };


    public ExercisePageBubleSort()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
     myCollection.ItemsSource = items;
    }




 private void check_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     int count = 0;
     foreach (var exerc in items)
     {
         if (exerc.OrderId == items.IndexOf(exerc))
         {
             count++;
         }
     }

     if (count == items.Count())
     {
         alertAboutSuccesful();
     }
     else alertAboutFail();
 }
```